# Let $X$ be a normed space. If the unit sphere is complete then the closed unit ball is complete.

Tags: functional-analysis

I need to know how to prove this result.

I have been searching information about this result during a long time but I have not found a correct proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in the unit ball,  we suppose it has an infinite of number of terms different of zero, otherwise the result is trivial. Since $\|x_n\|$ is bounded  you can extract a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $\|x_{n_k}\|$  converges and its terms are not zero.

A subsequence ${x_{n_l}\over{\|x_{n_l}\|}}$ of ${x_{n_k}\over{\|x_{n_k}\|}}$ converges towards $x$,

this implies that $\|x_{n_l}\|{x_{n_l}\over{\|x_{n_l}\|}}$ converges as the product of a convergent sequence in the normed space and a convergent sequence of scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Z$ be a completion of $X$ which $X$ is dense in. The unit sphere of $X$ is the unit sphere of $Z$ by completeness. For each $z\in Z$, normalize $z$ so that $z/||z||\in $ unit sphere of $X$. Hence $z\in X$, $Z=X$, and the closed unit ball of $X$ is complete.